# Формирование сложных массивов с объектами

Tags: javascript

есть объекты типа

```
{
  rank: low, 
  clan: hell, 
  cins: five, 
  name: Val, 
  skill: rage 
}
```

Нужно сформировать массив объектов что бы в результате был типа такого

```
{
  'low': {
    'hell': [тут вся остальная информация]
  }
}
```

В общем отфильтровать по `rank`, а внутри отфильтровать по `clan`. Я знаю как сделать простой фильтр через `reduce`, но не понимаю как сделать более сложный.

Вот например фильтр по rank

```
user.reduce((acc, c) => ((acc[c.rank] ? acc[c.rank].push(c) : acc[c.rank] = [c]), acc), {});
```

Comment: Вы сгупировали по рангу, дальше сделайте то же самое для каждого ранга и все

Comment: внутри reduce или где? Не совсем понимаю

Comment: сейчас, слеплю примерчик с вашего же кода )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто манипуляции с вашим же редьюсом

```js
const user = [{
    rank: 'low',
    clan: 'hell1',
    cins: 'five',
    name: 'Val',
    skill: 'rage'
  },
  {
    rank: 'low',
    clan: 'hell2',
    cins: '32',
    name: 'Va323l',
    skill: '12312'
  },
  {
    rank: 'low',
    clan: 'hell1',
    cins: 'five',
    name: 'Val',
    skill: 'rage'
  },
  {
    rank: 'high',
    clan: 'hell1',
    cins: 'five',
    name: 'Val',
    skill: 'rage'
  }
]

let a = user.reduce((acc, c) => (acc[c.rank] ? acc[c.rank].push(c) : acc[c.rank] = [c], acc), {})
Object.keys(a).forEach(k => {
  a[k] = a[k].reduce((acc, c) => (acc[c.clan] ? acc[c.clan].push(c) : acc[c.clan] = [c], acc), {})
})

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { rank: 'low', clan: 'hell', cins: 'five', name: 'Val', skill: 'rage' }, 
  { rank: 'low', clan: 'hell', cins: 'five2', name: 'Val2', skill: 'rage2' }
]; 

const result = data.reduce((rslt, { rank, clan, ...rest }) => {
  if (!rslt[rank] || !rslt[rank][clan]) 
    Object.assign(rslt, { [rank]: { [clan]: [] } }); 
  rslt[rank][clan].push({ ...rest }); 
  return rslt; 
}, {}); 
console.log(result);
```